# warning: Supported source version 'RELEASE_6' from annotation processor 'org.boundbox.processor.BoundBoxProcessor' less than -source '1.7'

Tags: android

I am getting this error while using the bound box jar in the android studio. When i see the search results for this kind of error what i observed is that same error issuing for other packages too. Is this a IDE problem or package problem.